# Generating MIDI-files in C

Tags: c, midi

I'm trying to generate MIDI files in C but I'm having bit trouble with the header chunk of the file.

So the MIDI header is in form of:

> chunk type-length-format-ntrks-division

The chunk type is the four ASCII characters 'MThd'; length is a 32-bit representation of the number 6 (high byte first). The rest are 16 bits.

So I created a Struct for the Header which is the following:

```
struct headerStruct {
    char chunktype[4]; //MThd
    long length; //32bit length
    int format;//16bit format
    int ntraks;//16bit number of tracks
    int division;//16bit division
};
```

Then I'm creating the struct in the code:

```
struct headerStruct *mthd = malloc(sizeof(struct headerStruct));
strncpy(mthd->chunktype, "MThd",4);
mthd->length = 6;
mthd->format = 0;
mthd->ntraks = 1;
mthd->division = 96;
```

And then I write the file (also with additional stuff not presented here) with fwrite, I'll leave that part of the code out. But if I look at the binary/hex with xxd and compare it to a correct midi file created with let's say ableton I see that they are different and mine is incorrect.

Correct midi header in hex:

> 4d54 6864 0000 0006 0000 0001 0060

My incorrect midi header in hex:

> 4d54 6864 0000 0000 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 6000 0000

What causes this? Is it an endianness issue or am I using wrong data types. I'm on 64bit os X 10.10.5. Because if I understood correctly 16 bit parts in the header should be ints and the length(32bit) long and so on. If it is an endianness thing how can I correct this. I read some endianness topics here but didn't really understand them.

Here's a link to pdf for more information on MIDI:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/Standard-MIDI-file-format-updated.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing your `int`s are 32-bit. Try `short` for 16-bit values.

Comment: I think you are right, but they are still in the wrong order, with length being int and rest shorts the hex looks like this:
4d54 6864 0600 0000 0000 0100 6000 0000
and should be this:
4d54 6864 0000 0006 0000 0001 0060
So there are still 16 bits too many. I was wondering if it because of the strncpy and the extra \0?

Comment: I would recommend that you include `stdint.h` and use `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, etc'. This will be more portable (since `int` can be 32 bits as well).

Comment: Check some other program that generates MIDI files, e.g., http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=seq/aplaymidi/arecordmidi.c;hb=HEAD.

Comment: Thanks CL I will go through that! Myst I was looking at those in some other topics here in stackoverflow but I'm not that experienced in C so how do those uint32_t uint16_t work? Like is it some kind of define thing in the begining of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIDI files require that the values be written in big-endian byte order, aka "network order"; you may find [`htnol`(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/htonl.3posix.html) and `htons`(3) to be useful:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
...
mthd->length = htonl(6);
mthd->ntraks = htons(1);
...
```

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks a lot! Now ableton accepts the file and well...crashes :D Guess I need to work on the MTrk part now.

Comment: Hmm. There are still 16 bits too many even though I changed the ints of my struct to shorts and long to int. Now the hex is like this:

4d54 6864 0000 0006 0000 0001 0060 0000

So the last two bytes are too much. Where they come from?

Comment: How are you writing the structure to the file? Don't use `sizeof(* mthd)`, because that is a multiple of 4 bytes (the alignment of `long`). Write the fields one by one.

Comment: Yea that did the trick! Great, thanks a lot! Why is it multiple of 4 bytes?

Comment: It's a multiple of 4 because it contains a `long` member, and the compiler needs to make the size of the struct a multiple of the alignment required for `long`, in case you make an array of them.

Comment: Ah alright! So the actual size with the sizeof method will always be the size of the biggest member in the struct?

Comment: @bnc: The size of a `struct` will always be a multiple of the alignment required for the member with the strictest alignment requirements.